# Next JS and Vercel Enviroment Variable problem

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, vercel

I used env variables through getServerSideProps and sent them to other components through props.

When I checked in the network tab, they are visible in the form of pageProps: { private_key : xxx }

How can I completely hide these variables?

Comment: We might need a little bit more information. But you can access your env variables from process.env.* anywhere in your code. Only variables with the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix can be accessed from the browser. All variables can be accessed from the server. So if you're seeing them in the network panel, you've probably already exposed them to the browser.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: I have some private keys that I want to remain secret but that can be used in components. I use getServerSideProps precisely to remain secret to the client-side, but when I send them to the components they appear in pageProps in the network tab